# GIF to MP4 + silence track

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using this solution to convert animated GIF to MP4.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294892

I'd like to add a silence audio track to the output.mp4

I think it will solve the problems I have when adding these generated mp4 files to other videos using avidemux.

How could I add a silence audio track using ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [anullsrc filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc):

```
ffmpeg -i input.gif -f lavfi -i anullsrc -vf "scale='trunc(in_w/2)*2':'trunc(in_h/2)*2',format=yuv420p,fps=10" -movflags +faststart -shortest video.mp4
```

- `-f lavfi -i anullsrc` Sets anullsrc filter as an input. Used to generate silent audio.
- `scale='trunc(in_w/2)*2':'trunc(in_h/2)*2'` Use scale filter to make output width & height to be divisible by 2 which is needed for 4:2:0 chroma subsampling.
- `format=yuv420p` Uses format filter to set chroma subsampling to 4:2:0 which is needed for compatible H.264.
- `fps=10` Set output frame rate to a compatible rate using fps filter.
- `-movflags +faststart` Makes output begin playback faster.
- `-shortest` Makes output the same duration as the shortest input (`input.gif` in this case as anullsrc has indefinite duration).

Comment: thanks, it's working! I was able to concatenate videos using Avidemux thanks to this audio track.  It has solved also my problem with Avidemux